# Convert a column of integers to time in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a column of data with 'int' format I want to change it to date time format, my time is like 94320 that should be 9:43:20 or another example: 143020 should be 14:30:20. I use

```
quote['SellTime'] = pd.to_datetime(quote['SellTime'], unit = 's')
```

but it add 1970-01-01 to the beginning of time that I don't need it.

Comment: so can you give more examples? what happens if you have "1333" is that 01:03:33 or 13:03:03 ?

Comment: data is actual time and it is never less than 5 digits, it starts at 60000(6:00:00) and ends at 140000(14:00:00)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'SellTime': [94320, 143020]})
>>> df
   SellTime
0     94320
1    143020
>>> df['New'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SellTime'], format='%H%M%S').dt.time
>>> df
   SellTime       New
0     94320  09:43:20
1    143020  14:30:20
```

Answer (score 0):

in plain python:

```
def format_time(value):
    t2 = str(value)
    if len(t2) == 5:
        return "0%s:%s:%s" % (t2[0], t2[1:3], t2[3:5])
    return "%s:%s:%s" % (t2[0:2], t2[2:4], t2[4:6])


print(format_time(60000))
print(format_time(120000))
```

returns

```
06:00:00
12:00:00
```

this function assumes that all values are correct. There is no check on e.g. hour 55